# React Quill Installation

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem while installing `react-quill`.

The error message I have got is:

```
unable to resolve dependency tree.
```

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please, post errors using the `code` formatter instead of images.

Comment: it's issues related to dependency conflict pls install using `--legacy-peer-deps`. `npm install react-quill --legacy-peer-deps`.